# How to remove all the documents from an index in Redisearch?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, spring-data-redis, redisearch

I want all the documents to be removed from a particular index in Redisearch. I have come across commands for deleting records with the documentid known. Can we delete all the records without using documentids?

Please suggest something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just drop the index `FT.DROPINDEX` and recreate it?

Comment: I want only the data to be removed from the index, as recreating index might take much time.

Comment: And also even if I have to drop the index itself, I want all the records to be completely removed from redis in my requirement, for which I came across the command 'FT.dropindex indexname DD'. But I didn't get where to set 'DD' option when running the query through jredisearch API. Could you please tell where can I look for that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably already solved in your case, but since the google sends here as one of the first result and it's still not resolved:
Use `FT.DROP "indexName"`.
It's not to be found in the official documentation list but for me it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in both ways like:

1. DropIndex with all documents by running this command -
   --  FT.DROPINDEX yourindex DD
2. OR if you need to fetch all documents and delete by id you can do it through a loop or pipeline